# R web scraping from XML

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to web scraping. I am trying to scrape the below XML file on the the NY Fed reserve website using the XML library

fedops <- xmlparse("https://markets.newyorkfed.org/api/ambs/all/results/details/search.sdmx.xml?startdate=03/02/2020&enddate=04/07/2020")

but then i get the below error. I am not sure how to proceed here, it appears to be an xml file, but maybe i should be using rvest and read_html? any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'ddate=04/07/2020'

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use `xml2` to work with XML:

```
library(xml2)
pg <- read_xml("https://markets.newyorkfed.org/api/ambs/all/results/details/search.sdmx.xml?startdate=03/02/2020&enddate=04/07/2020")
sections <- pg %>% xml_find_all("//n1:Section")
```